# Minimization and HTTP Compression using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I am very new to VBScript so can someone please tell me if it is possible to do minimization's and http compression using vbscript..I have different files like css and js that I would like to minimize and compress.

Thanks

Comment: HTTP compression is the job of the webserver. It's unclear to me what you mean by "minimization".

Comment: I know it's the job of the web server but I was thinking if there is a way I can do that myself through some script so these files are already compressed and the web server will not do the compression while serving the files since they will be already compresses...Minizing means removing any extra spaces or any extra stuff.

Comment: Your time would be better spent on making the code more efficient than on trying to do things the webserver can do well enough. As for the other thing, that's called "minification". Check the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29), it lists some tools.

Comment: But won't be it a performance gain if the files are already http compressed and the web server just servers them instead of doing it at runtime

Comment: Perhaps, but I doubt it'd be significant. Again, your time would be better spent optimizing the code than trying to do the webserver's work.

Comment: Actually, most servers (including IIS) can make use of caching so files are only compressed once.